# How can I correctly send android emojies charecter via JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, emoji

I tried everything I could find about how to do this but none does seem to work, it sounds simple but I can't figure it out. Here is what the JSON output looks like when putting The Emojies from the EditText to the JSONObject

`"reply_text":"` <<< see it works here but after sending it to the server and retrieving it it shows like this

> > > > > > ????????

Comment: I logged the output of the JSON and the emojies show as SQUARES, not charecters

Comment: Without the code, we have no idea if you're writing correctly or not.

Comment: I am not doing anything complex I just get the text from the editText and put it in a json object and send the json object as a string to the server, and the server puts it in a database which are all UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Set your encode to UTF-16. It should work.

Comment: Okay, but what about the database which is UTF-8 should I change the database as well

Comment: Theoretically, UTF-8 should work too. Show us your code. It could be another problem.